# Does a discharging capacitor in an AC circuit add additional voltage to circuit?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis

In an RC circuit with an ac voltage source, after the capacitor becomes charged and then the sign of the ac voltage flips, does the discharging capacitor add additional voltage to the circuit compared to when the capacitor had no charge on it?

Thanks

Comment: well, half the time it adds, half the time it subtracts; overall it's a wash and the sine wave is shifted to the right. Capacitors resist (slow down) voltage changes, so peaks and zero-cross happen later than w/o capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking in terms of adding additional voltage, think of the capacitor as causing a delay. The RC circuit you mention causes the voltage the lag the current.

This might be of interest to read [Capacitors in AC Circuits](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/ac-capacitance.html)

Hope that helps